# Extjs 4 Grid renderer called after reconfigure

Tags: grid, extjs4, renderer

The problem I am facing is with the EXTJs grid.

I reconfigure the grid using the method grid.reconfigure(store,cols)

I have a custom renderer for my columns in the grid, in the renderer I call the function to set the width of the column accoridng to the content

The problem I am facing is that even though on the reconfigure method my renderer is called but my colWidth is not set in the first time. But on refreshing the grid it is set.

To give an example

```
 someFunction:function(grid,store){
    cols.push({
        text: //something,
        dataIndex : //something
        renderer : renderer,    //function call to renderer
        width:100,
    });
    grid.reconfigure(store,cols);}

    renderer:function(value){
    colwidth(value);
    return value; }

    colwidth:function(value){
        // compute content length
        return 50;
    }
```